# Binding List to a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I want to bind my list to a comboBox:

```
 private BindingList<Tool> toolList = new BindingList<Tool>();
```

XAML-Binding:

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding toolList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
   SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue= "{Binding toolList}"   Height="22" 
   Name="comboBoxTools" Width="185" SelectionChanged="comboBoxTools_SelectionChanged" />
```

The Objects of the List have the member Name and Path and I want that the Name appears in the comboBox.
When I add a new Object to the List it doesn't appears in the ComboBox:

```
  private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
        input.ShowDialog();
        inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

        if (inputNewTool != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
            dlg.Filter = "Application (.exe)|*.exe";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                toolList.Add(tool);
                //comboBoxTools.Items.Add(tool);
            }                
       }            
     }
```

Now with ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Tool> toolList = new ObservableCollection<Tool>();
  private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
        input.ShowDialog();
        inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

        if (inputNewTool != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
            dlg.Filter = "Application (.exe)|*.exe";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                toolList.Add(tool);
                //comboBoxTools.Items.Add(tool);
            }                
       }            
     }
```

XAML-Binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=toolList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue= "{Binding Path=toolList}"   Height="22" 
Name="comboBoxTools" Width="185" SelectionChanged="comboBoxTools_SelectionChanged" />
```

Comment: Instead of a BindingList try and ObservableCollection

Comment: I replaced List to ObservableCollection and nothing is changed :(

Comment: You do know you need a public property for binding?

Comment: When i change the property of toolList to public it doesn't help out

Comment: Show your code.   Do you have a get?

Comment: What dou you want to see exactly? I added the code above

Comment: public alone does not it a public property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ObservableCollection<Tool> ToolList 
{
   get { return toolList; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I completed but the problem isn't solved :(. The binding is not realised

Comment: Did you change the binding to ToolList?

Comment: Actual XAMl Code: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ToolList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Height="22" Name="comboBoxTools" Width="185" SelectionChanged="comboBoxTools_SelectionChanged" DataContext="{Binding}" />

Comment: Take out the DataContext="{Binding}" and in the ctor first line add this.DataContext = this;

Comment: in the constructor of the MainWindow i have to add this?

Comment: What comes after the word add? Come on apply yourself.

Comment: I don't get it where i have to set the statement this.DataContext = this

Comment: Already answered.  Come on apply yourself.  Find a tutorial on binding.